« Ne savoir pas répondre » vs. « ne savoir pas comment répondre»
Qu'est-ce que « comment » ajoute ou change ?

Je ne sais pas répondre a ces questions.

François-Xavier Coquin, Le verbe et l'histoire (2002)

Je craignais qu’il me pose des questions auxquelles je n’aurais pas su pas répondre, sur ma musique, sur mes choix

PIERRE BOULEZ, UN MENTOR ET UN AMI. ENTRETIEN
By Matthias Pintscher, le 25/01/2016
contre

J’ai compris que c’était la même chose que ‘à tes souhaits!’, cependant je ne savais pas comment repondre.

Pratiques discursives et acquisition des langues étrangères, p. 314.

le sujet ne sais pas comment repondre

La dialectologie aperçu historique et méthodes d'enquêtes linguistiques, Volume 38 (1992).

La source de la deuxième citation contient une erreur de transcription. Pierre Boulez n'a pas pu dire je n'aurais pas su pas répondre mais très probablement je n'aurais pas su quoi répondre.

Il n'y a pas de différence de sens très significative entre les différentes façons de le dire qu'on ne sait pas ce qu'il faut répondre à une question ou à quelque chose en général :

Je ne sais répondre.
Je ne sais que répondre.
Je ne sais comment répondre.
Je ne sais pas comment répondre.
Je sais pas comment répondre.
Je ne sais quoi répondre.
Je ne sais pas quoi répondre.
Je sais pas quoi répondre.
Je ne sais qu'y répondre.

S'il fallait trouver une nuance, comment ouvre plus de possibilités que quoi ou que. Avec comment, on peut se demander quoi répondre mais aussi par exemple se demander par quel moyen on va le faire (par téléphone, courrier, message, etc.)
Il y a en revanche des différences de registre entre ces diverses propositions.
